# Hadoop: Performance degradation when increasing block sizes?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Has anyone seen any performance degradation when increasing the block size in Hadoop? We're setting up a cluster and we're expecting a large amount of data (100s of GBs) coming in per day that we need to store, so my thought was we could increase the block size a good amount. However, there were concerns if there was a point where it would slow down the MapReduce jobs that will be run. The only way I could see it happening is if the number of blocks was fewer than the number of tasks that could be run on the cluster.

Does anyone have any additional information on this subject?

Answer (score 2):

Here are several things to consider:

- Too small files are not recommended - filesystem metadata kept in namenode memory - hardware limits to number of files.
- Default block size on HDFS is 64MB, but 128MB is most common case in production servers.
- HDFS blocks are large by default to have larger transfer times of block when compared to seek times - therefore time to transfer
  large files consisting of many blocks operates at disk transfer time.
- MapReduce tasks operate on one block at a time, so if having too few tasks (less then nodes in cluster), your jobs might be slow.
- Putting block size to be near approximate size of your files on HDFS is not good idea, because it increases probability of faulty data. Assume you have 1 file of 1GB and your block size is also 1 GB. Assume also that replication factor is 3 on your cloud(default or most common at least). This means that you would have your entire file as one block on 3 machines. This is different compared to having only some blocks of file replicated on 3 machines.
- If the number of blocks (of input processing files) is fewer than number of tasks you can run concurrently on your environment - this is GOOD - it means you are processing all input data with maximum parallelism, and still have free resources.

Comment: Thanks, but outside of the one about the block size near the size of the files, I've seen the same information in several places.  I'm specifically looking for a case where someone has run into performance degradation due to increasing the block size.